# Use Regular Expressions to remove unwanted numbering R

Tags: r, regex, dataframe, duplicates

I have a dataframe in R that I need to remove unwanted numbering from, seen in the "Event" columns in the below example.

```
df <- data.frame( Name = c("Jim","Jim","Jim","Jim","Jim","Jim","Jim","Jim","Jim","Jim",
                           "Sue","Sue","Sue","Sue","Sue","Sue","Sue","Sue","Sue","Sue"),
                  Dates = c("2010-1-1", "2010-1-2", "2010-01-5","2010-01-17","2010-01-20",
                            "2010-01-29","2010-02-6","2010-02-9","2010-02-16","2010-02-28",
                            "2010-1-1", "2010-1-2", "2010-01-5","2010-01-17","2010-01-20",
                            "2010-01-29","2010-02-6","2010-02-9","2010-02-16","2010-02-28"),
                  Event.1 = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1),
                  Event.2 = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1),
                  Event.3 = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1))
```

I know I can do this in python using the re module, with this syntax -

`df.columns = [re.sub("(.*?)(\.\d+)", "\\1", c) for c in df.columns]`

Can anybody tell me the R equivalent?

The resulting dataframe would be:

```
df <- data.frame( Name = c("Jim","Jim","Jim","Jim","Jim","Jim","Jim","Jim","Jim","Jim",
                           "Sue","Sue","Sue","Sue","Sue","Sue","Sue","Sue","Sue","Sue"),
                  Dates = c("2010-1-1", "2010-1-2", "2010-01-5","2010-01-17","2010-01-20",
                            "2010-01-29","2010-02-6","2010-02-9","2010-02-16","2010-02-28",
                            "2010-1-1", "2010-1-2", "2010-01-5","2010-01-17","2010-01-20",
                            "2010-01-29","2010-02-6","2010-02-9","2010-02-16","2010-02-28"),
                  Event = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1),
                  Event = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1),
                  Event = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1))
```

Maintaining the 3 duplicate "Event" columns.

Comment: It is not recommended and data.frame by default doesn't allow that.  if you check the output from the data.frame, call, it still returns the `.1`, `.2` etc because of `check.names = TRUE` by default

Comment: Thanks for the reply @akrun, that's the problem I'm running into. The csv file I am creating the dataframe from has duplicate columns and R is automatically adding numbers to each duplicate. I need to remove the so I can group/combine the duplicate columns to analyze.

Comment: Instead of making them have the same column name use `startsWith` or in tidyverse `starts_with` to pick out the columns.

Answer (score 2):

In `base R`, we can use `trimws` (but not recommended as `data.frame` by default uses `check.names = TRUE` and this triggers `make.names/make.unique` to add those suffix numbers when there are duplicates in column names)

```
names(df) <- trimws(names(df), whitespace = "\\.\\d+")
```

---

If we are reading from `csv`, an option is `check.names = FALSE`

```
df <- read.csv("yourfile.csv", check.names = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thanks! Though I've now created a new problem... when I try to group it's giving an error because of the duplicates. I realized if gather the data first (pivot long) I could just apply this to the column. Do you know the syntax to apply this to all the rows in a single column instead?

Comment: What I can do though is melt the data to long format with the original names .1, .2, .3, etc. and then apply the regex to the all the data in the column to allow me to group.

Comment: What I'm wondering is how you apply it to the regex "name" column specifically, say if I were to pivot the colum with the numbers included.... then remove them from the column? My actual dataset has 893 variables so I can't select them by their column name.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246827/discussion-between-john-conor-and-akrun).

Comment: I believe `dplyr::rename` was allowing us to have duplicated names in tibbles. Have they made a change to that?

Comment: @M-- not sure.  But some tidyverse functions still returns error with duplicate column names

Comment: Just found this thread: https://github.com/tidyverse/tibble/issues/431 it's been "fixed" since.